# Comparing Generic Types in TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm working on a frontend project in Angular for my company in which we query different objects from an API (like Users, Products, etc).

I am currently trying to generalize our services which handle data transfer between our components and the API as they all do pretty much the same (trying to keep it DRY). To achieve this I need to make different API calls depending on the type of my generic.

It basically boils down to this:

```js
public foo<TMyType>(){
        if (TMyType === TypeA) {
            //do stuff
        } else if (TMyType === TypeB) {
            //do other stuff
        } else {
            throw new Error('Invalid type');
        }
    }
```

Note that I do not want to pass the actual object, but only decide on what to do depending on the generic type I call the function with.
I feel like there should be a very simple way to achieve this, but I cannot figure it out.

Many thanks

Comment: Types not exist at the runtime. Thus, such comparsions will not work any way. You need to pass real objects

Comment: I find it quite humourous that a language called TypeScript removes types at runtime. I know that beneath it is just plain JS, but you catch my drift - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do types comparison on runtime, but you can do something like this:

```js
function foo<T extends TypeA | TypeB>(a: T) {
    
}
```

`T extends TypeA | TypeB` means that generic type `T` can only be `TypeA` or `TypeB`

to distinguish typeA from typeB you have to find a specific property which can tell them apart

for example:

```js
type TypeA = string
type TypeB = { test: string }

function foo<T extends TypeA | TypeB>(a: T) {
    if(typeof a === "string") {
         //... a is TypeA
    } else if("test" in a) {
         //... a is TypeB
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually thought of that as well but I cannot do that as the types get generated and are therefore fixed - thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could remove some of boilerplate with class inheritance.

```
class GenericRestService {
     protected endpoint: string = '/stuff';

     constructor(protected httpClient: HttpClient) {}

     makeACall<T>(param: string): Observable<T> {
          return this.httpClient.get<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${param}`)
               .pipe( 
          // some stuff here
               ); 
     }
}
```

```
class SpecificRestService extends GenericRestService {
    endpoint = '/otherThings';
}
```

Comment: This is probably how I will do it if I can't figure out how to make it work otherwise. I wanted to avoid creating a service for every API object as this could get bloated quite fast - thanks